# How to import mysql dumpfile?

Tags: mysql

How to import MySQL Dumpfile, SQL Datafile Into My Database. I am using MySql and basically want to attach that dump file to drupal.

Please guide , I am not using PhpMyadmin.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is one of the easiest ways to do this if you don't have command line access on the server. Any specific reason why you can't use it?

Comment: i have configured apache, php and mysql individually(AMP stack) , never used phpmyadmin

Comment: If you have command line access to your server, you can use `mysql`. See e.g. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/import-mysql-dumpfile-sql-datafile-into-my-database/ if you don't, installing phpMyAdmin is the best idea.

Comment: for the time being i am running on localhost only..anywayz thanks

Comment: Then you have `mysql` installed somewhere on your machine. You can use the method described in the article. (ignore the "copy datadump to remote server" bit)

Comment: There are many other MySQL clients that allows importing SQL-dumps. You can install MySQL and use its [command-line tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html). Also you can use one of GUI tools, e.g. - [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/).

Comment: i have the command line tool...but how to include dump?

Comment: Do you mean - how to execute SQL-file against MySQL database? If so, try something like this - `mysql --options... < dump.sql`. There are examples in documentation.

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql -h yourmysqlhost -u yourmysqlusername -pyourmysqlpassword yourdrupaldatabasename < /path/to/mysql_dump_file.sql
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, please consider providing more information to describe the code/command you've recommended.